# cmake: can't locate library with find_package

Tags: cmake

I'm new to CMake, and currently I'm  trying to figure out how to locate libraries using  find_package(). 
My goal is to locate CryptoPP library.
When I run CMake it prints:

```
CMake Error at my_app/CMakeLists.txt:66 (message):
  Failed to find CryptoPP.
```

My folder hierarchy and CMake files are given below. So, what's wrong?

[image]

```
#====================================================================================
# my_app/my_app/cmake_modules/FindCryptopp.cmake ====================================
#====================================================================================

set(HDR_LIST sha.h 
            rsa.h 
            osrng.h 
            files.h 
            base32.h 
            randpool.h
            default.h)

set(LIB_LIST cryptlib.lib 
            cryptlibd.lib)

# check that includes we need are present
find_path(cryptopp_INCLUDE_DIR HDR_LIST PATHS ../../3rd_party_libs/cryptopp560)

# check that libraries we need are present
find_library(cryptopp_LIBRARIES LIB_LIST PATHS ../../3rd_party_libs/cryptopp560/win32/vc12 NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

set(Cryptopp_FOUND TRUE)

if (NOT cryptopp_INCLUDE_DIR)
    set(Cryptopp_FOUND FALSE)
endif (NOT cryptopp_INCLUDE_DIR)

if (NOT cryptopp_LIBRARIES)
    set(Cryptopp_FOUND FALSE)
endif (NOT cryptopp_LIBRARIES)

#====================================================================================
# my_app/my_app/CMakeLists.txt ======================================================
#====================================================================================
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0015 NEW)

project("my_app")
set(HDR_LIST foo.h)
set(SRC_LIST foo.cpp
            main.cpp)

add_executable(my_app ${SRC_LIST} ${HDR_LIST})

target_link_libraries(my_app my_lib)


set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_modules)
find_package(Cryptopp)

if (Cryptopp_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Includes for Cryptopp found in ${cryptopp_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    message(STATUS "Libraries for Cryptopp found in ${cryptopp_LIBRARIES}")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Failed to find CryptoPP.")
endif()
```

Comment: You should not add paths to find_path and find_library. Add them to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` when you invoke cmake. You should not check for the whole list of headers, but for only one. You can search for multiple names by adding NAMES but it will look for one name out of the list. Same is true for find_library.

Comment: @usr1234567 will try today your suggestion. But why presented approach doesn't work? It seems like it completely matches to CMake documentation.

Comment: No, it does not. You check for different files, the documentation wants to check for one file which can have different names. And you missed the `NAMES` in front of your list.

Comment: I created an answer which you can accept to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search for file alternative put `NAMES` in front of the list. Without only one file name is allowed.